# Full screen enabled ipad to windows streaming VNC

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation, remote-desktop, streaming

I'm streaming my windows desktop with Splashtop Streamer to my iPad.

However it doesn't support full screen windows apps. Are there any apps which does support full screen windows apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jump Desktop](http://jumpdesktop.com) seems to be one of the best iOS clients for streaming in my experience. I prefer [Screens](http://edovia.com/en/screens.html) for a multitude of reasons when I am doing system administration tasks, but for end users working for hours at a time on Windows via the iPad, Jump seems to be the winner in terms of features, shortcuts and usability.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried RDP? There are several Remote Desktop apps, eg PocketCloud that can connect to a Windows PC using the native RDP server.